# Are macros values, data types, identifiers, variables, constants, or ...?

Tags: macros

Macros exist in many programming languages, for example, C.

1. A data type is a set of values with operations on the values. Are
   macros values, or data types?
2. Are macros identifiers, variables, or constants?
3. Are macros something not belonging to a programming language,
   and something that will be translated to the programming language in
   the preprocessing step of compilation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

[*macros*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_%28computer_science%29) have a very different meaning in C (or C++) than e.g. in Common Lisp or Scheme (or some [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) programming language).

<sup>In particular, in Lisp or Scheme you can have macros with some local [binding scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29). In C or C++ the scope is textual, always from the `#define` till the end of translation unit or some `#undef`. And C/C++ macros cannot define other macros (but you could do that in Lisp)</sup>

In C and C++, the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) is the first phase of the compiler, and operates at a textual level (in particular, the C/C++ preprocessor does not see any [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), only [lexical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) tokens). The compiler proper sees only preprocessed form (so your point 3 is true, and your points 1 and 2 become irrelevant). So macros are living in a different world than the values or variables. In particular, macros could be defined without even being a well formed expression or instruction, like in

```
int counter;
/// UGLY!
#define MY_BEGIN { counter++;
#define MY_END(N) N--; }
void myfun(void)
  MY_BEGIN printf("counter=%d\n", counter); MY_END(counter)
```

<sup>But I feel that the above code is ugly!</sup>

A C or C++ compiler gives you the ability to get the preprocessed form. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) use e.g. `gcc -C -E foo.c > foo.i` to get into file `foo.i` (which you could inspect with some editor or pager) the preprocessed form of source file `foo.c` ... and read the documentation of [cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/), i.e. of GCC preprocessor.

Notice that C/C++ macros are not able to generate easily any kind of code. For example, you cannot code [parser generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler) like [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/) with only C/C++ macros (you need some *external* C code generating tool like `bison`). C++ has [templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28C%2B%2B%29), but you cannot for instance easily code a printer generator (i.e. print all fields of some `struct` given as a template argument) or a [serializer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) generator with them. Such things are possible in Lisp.

In [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp), macros are homogeneous with the programming language, and are *values*. the [evaluation and compilation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_.htm) process is very different from C. For example, with [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/) implementation of Common Lisp, the evaluator and compiler is part of *every* application, and applications in Lisp routinely build some Lisp expressions at runtime then compile them (at runtime also). So the code itself is changing at runtime!

Very *grossly speaking*, in Lisp macros are some kind of value (i.e. is a datatype); in [Scheme](http://schemers.org/) or [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (a domain specific language to extend and customize [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)), macro definitions introduce some kind of binding. (But things are in fact more subtle, so this is a simplification and is somehow "wrong"). Read about [quasi-quotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-quotation).

C.Queinnec's book [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://pagesperso-systeme.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/LiSP.html) explains that quite well. Scott's book [Programming Language Pragmatics](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/pragmatics/) is also an interesting reading.

Comment: Thanks. Are they values of what data type in CL?

Comment: Grossly speaking, of some macro datatype.